# Which way does the dipole moment point for this pair of charges?

Tags: electrostatics, dipole, dipole-moment

I am quite confused.

I am given a question where $\vec p=p\hat z$ and $\vec p=p\hat x$

Where p is the dipole moment. ($\vec p=q\vec d$)

Assuming $\hat z$ is upwards, $\hat y$ is to the right, and $\hat x$ is towards us, would  $\vec p=p\hat z$ be[image]

As in, it's pointing up towards $\hat z$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. For a pair of equal charges, the dipole moment points from the negative charge to the positive one.

If in doubt, though, just use the (real) definition,
$$
\mathbf p = \sum_j q_j \mathbf r_j,
$$
where $\mathbf p$ is the dipole moment of a collection of charges $q_j$ at positions $\mathbf r_j$.

Comment: Thank you! That definitely with this question quite a bit.